# generate a SQL query from arguments

Tags: shell-script, shell

Im trying to make an SQL query from user-provided arguments.

Let's say the schema name, table name and some where conditions are given by the arguments.

```
schema='myschema'
table='testtable'
where_column='dob'
where_column2='firstname'
```

From the above arguments, I can generate the below SQL statement:

```
select * from myschema.testable where dob **i can add some value later** and firstname **some value**
```

Next time, we use the following arguments

```
schema='myschema'
table='testtable'
where_column='dob'
```

and we're only interested in filtering `dob`. So the SQL query would be

```
select * from myschema.testable where dob ** I can add some value later**
```

Im stuck building this. If two `where` condition arguments are there, then put everything in the query with `AND` in between. If only one `where` condition is provided, then just use that only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would that work for you?

```
#!/bin/bash

from=$1; shift # remove the first argument from $@

for i; do
  if [ -n "$where" ]; then # if "$where" is not empty then...
     where+=" AND "
  fi
  where+="$i"
done

printf 'SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s;\n' "$from" "$where"
```

The first argument is `schema.table` and the following arguments are used for the `WHERE` clause.

Output:

```
$ ./script.sh myschema.table "dob = 'dib'"
SELECT * FROM myschema.table WHERE dob = 'dib';
$ ./script.sh myschema.table "dob = 'dib'" "firstname = 'Bhuvanesh'" "foo LIKE 'bar%'"
SELECT * FROM myschema.table WHERE dob = 'dib' AND firstname = 'Bhuvanesh' AND foo LIKE 'bar%';
```